# Data-driven sharing rule?

Tags: sharing

Is there a way to set up a sharing rule that shares a record with a user who is specified in a user field on the record being shared?

Answer (score 2):

Brad,

You can consider using [Apex Sharing](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_bulk_sharing_creating_with_apex.htm) for your use case.

When a record is created or updated with a value in the user field, then using a trigger on your object, you can create the sharing with the user being populated on the record.

the reference link has some sample code as well.